# Will external ip be stuck on pending if the pod fails?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, devops

I have a nodejs app which connects to external db , the db will refuse the connection until I whitelist my ip or my pod will fail , so is it possible that my external ip for the service will be stuck on pending if the pod fails?

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible that my external ip for the service will be stuck on pending if the pod fails?

The Service and Pods are created separately.  So if you're creating a LoadBalancer-type Service and your cluster is correctly configured, you should be able to get an `externalIP:` address for it even if the Pods aren't correctly starting up.

But:

> I have a nodejs app which connects to external db , the db will refuse the connection until I whitelist my ip

The Service only accepts inbound connections.  In a cloud environment like AWS, the `externalIP:` frequently is the address of a specific load balancer.  Outbound requests to a database won't usually come from this address.

If your cluster is in the same network environment as the database, you probably need to allow every individual worker node in the database configuration.  Tools like the cluster autoscaler can cause the node pool to change, so if you can configure the entire CIDR block containing the cluster that's easier.  If the cluster is somewhere else and outbound traffic passes through a NAT gateway of some sort, then you need to allow that gateway.